# Is there a way to make this method parsing tweets in Python efficient?

Tags: algorithm, performance, python-2.7, processing-efficiency

I have a script that queries Twitter then counts the most Retweeted tweets from the result sets. I am very new to programming, so the code is ugly for sure but it does what I want it to do.

It does take time to count the retweets. Is there a way to make the function "count_top_rt()" more efficient (i.e. run faster)??

```
import datetime

#Twitter API package
import tweepy

#Auth to Twitter
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler('<key goes here>')
auth.set_access_token('<key goes here>')

#connect to Twitter API
#currently in a try/catch block to avoid blowing out the API rate limit
try:
    api
    print("Twitter API connection already set.")
except NameError:
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    print("Setting Twitter API connection.")

#dictionary to store popular tweets
top_retweets = {}
#dictionary to store popular tags
top_tags = {}
#list to temp store hashtags - will fix where this sits later
hstgl = []

#FUNCTIONS
def get_tweets(search_term, num_results):
    #This pulls down 450 tweets. Not sure why it is 450
    tweet_set = tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                                   q=search_term,
                                   rpp=100,
                                   result_type="recent",
                                   include_entities=True,
                                   lang="en").items(num_results)
    return tweet_set

def count_top_rt(tweet):
    print "Count RT start ", datetime.datetime.now()
    for tweet in tweet_set:
        #test if this is a retweet
        if hasattr(tweet, 'retweeted_status'):
            #if already in top rt list, increment count
            if tweet.retweeted_status.id_str in top_retweets:
                top_retweets[tweet.retweeted_status.id_str] += 1
            else:
                #if not in top rt list, add it
                top_retweets[tweet.retweeted_status.id_str] = 1
        else:
            pass
    print "Count RT end ", datetime.datetime.now()

def show_top_rt(top_retweets):
    print 
    print "Most Retweeted"
    rt_count = -1
    sort_most_rt = sorted(top_retweets.iteritems(), key=lambda (k,v): (v,k))
    for key, value in sort_most_rt:
        rt_count += 1
        #minimum number of retweets before displaying
        if value > 3:
            print "(Tweet #" + str(rt_count) + ")" + "%s: %s" % (key, value)
            tweet = api.get_status(key)
            print(tweet.text)
            print("Tweeted by " + tweet.user.screen_name) + "\n"

def usr_post_rt():
    rt = raw_input("RT # ?? ")
    #test if the input is an integer
    try:
        int(rt)
    except ValueError:
        #allow user to terminate
        if rt == 'x':
            os.system('clear')
            pass
        #prompt user to select number of tweet to RT
        else:
            print("Please select a number")
            usr_post_rt()
    else:
        #RT the selected tweet
        if 0 <= int(rt) <= len(sort_most_rt):
            #<NEED CODE HERE FOR RT> RT the selected tweet
            api.retweet(sort_most_rt[int(rt)][0])
            #print(sort_most_rt[int(rt)])
            usr_post_rt()
        else:
            #make sure the tweet is in range 
            print("out of numeric range")
            usr_post_rt()

#MAIN
print "Time now is", datetime.datetime.now()

#get X tweets for the search term. Using 0 for X = max results
tweet_set = get_tweets("Sydney fun", 0)
#Count the top retweets
count_top_rt(tweet_set)
#Count the top hashtags 
    #count_top_htag(tweet_set)
#DISPLAY RESULTS
show_top_rt(top_retweets)
#allow the user to post selected retweets
usr_post_rt()
```

Comment: The first rule of performance optimisation: measure. First, scientifically prove the method is slow. Optimise only after that.

Comment: `count_top_rt(tweet)` has a single input parameter, which is never used. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: How would `api` ever be set when you test it?

Comment: It doesn't seem fast but I have no way of knowing.  Time now is 2016-11-21 21:38:55.300544
Get tweet start:  2016-11-21 21:38:55.300930
Get tweet end  2016-11-21 21:38:55.309481
Count RT start  2016-11-21 21:38:55.483905
Count RT end  2016-11-21 21:39:44.069743

Comment: @jonsharpe running (more than once) the file from the terminal (e.g. execfile('file.py')

Comment: @inspectorG4dget good point. I did a poor job of passing 'tweet_set' there. I'm a total programming noob, and got lucky that the for loop picked up the tweet_set variable.